# Haskell instance show

Tags: haskell, module, instance, show

hi I have a haskell module which have this data type

```
data Blabla = Blabla [Integer]
[Char]
[(Integer,Char,Char,Integer,String)] Integer
```

I want to show them like that with using instance show

```
integers=[1,2,3]
chars=[a,b,c]
specialList=[(1,a,b,2,cd),(3,b,c,4,gh)]
interger=44
```

thanx for helping...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you just want the default style, simply adding `deriving Show` to the end of the line as below should do the job.

```
data Blabla = Blabla [Integer] [Char] [(Integer,Char,Char,Integer,String)] Integer deriving Show
```

Will work fine as all of the primitive types that Blabla is built from are "showable".  For example

```
*Main> Blabla [1,2,3] "abc" [(1,'A','B',2,"Three")] 54
Blabla [1,2,3] "abc" [(1,'A','B',2,"Three")] 54
```

It might be better to build `Blabla` as a named structure

```
 data BlaBlu = BlaBlu {
    theNumbers :: [Integer] ,
    theIdentifier :: [Char] ,
    theList :: [(Integer,Char,Char,Integer,String)]  ,
    theInteger :: Integer
 } deriving Show
```

By doing this you might be able to make the structure make more sense.

```
*Main> BlaBlu [1,2,3] "abc" [(1,'A','B',2,"Three")] 54
BlaBlu {theNumbers = [1,2,3], theIdentifier = "abc", theList = [(1,'A','B',2,"Three")], theInteger = 54}
```

Do the same thing for the list structure and hopefully the code will be more readable.

If you want to write your own instance of `Show` so you can customize it then you can remove the `deriving Show` and just write your own instance, such as:

```
instance Show Blabla where                                                                                       
    show (Blabla ints chars list num) =                                                                            
    "integers = " ++ show ints ++ "\n" ++                                                                        
    "chars = " ++ show chars ++ "\n" ++                                                                          
    "specialList = " ++ show list ++ "\n" ++                                                                     
    "integer = " ++ show num
```

Where the implementation produces roughly the output you asked in the original question.

```
*Main> Blabla [1,2,3] "abc" [(1,'A','B',2,"Three")] 54
integers = [1,2,3]
chars = "abc"
specialList = [(1,'A','B',2,"Three")]
integer = 54
```

Comment: no thats not what i ask, i ask how can i show ['a','b','c'] like [a,b,c] etc.

Comment: OK, sorry I had trouble understanding the question.  I've added a little bit about how you can write your own instance of show above.