# Haskell - Show instance multiple datatypes

Tags: haskell, types, instance, show

I'm currently making a chess game for a school assignment and my pieces are defined

```
    data Piece = Piece { piecetype :: PieceType, color :: PieceColor }
    data PieceType = Pawn | Knight | Bishop | Rook | Queen | King
    data PieceColor = Black | White deriving Eq
```

now I have to print a piece as a single char (king = k, queen = q, knight = n, etc.) for black pieces the value is a capital of its white value (king = K, queen = Q, knight = N, etc.)
So I made three instances of show

```
    instance Show PieceColor where
        show Black = "B"
        show White = "W"

    instance Show PieceType where
        show Pawn = "P"
        show Knight = "N"
        show Bishop = "B"
        show Rook = "R"
        show Queen = "Q"
        show King = "K"
```

and the third one is the problem

```
    instance Show Piece where
        show (piecetype, color) = show piecetype 
                                  if show color == "W"
                                  then show piecetype
                                  else toUpper (show piecetype)
```

I receive the following error (also I tried a lot more than this but according to this link I seem pretty close [Something somewhat similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677749/haskell-instance-show)

```
Couldn't match expected type `Piece' with actual type `(t0, t1)'
```

I appreciate any help
Kind regards, Me

Comment: it should be `show (Piece piecetype color)` instead of `show (piecetype,color)`.

Comment: a few errors on my end and it works like a charm, thanks Satvik

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Direct Answer:

```
instance Show Piece where
    show (Piece piecetype Black) = map toLower $ show piecetype
    show (Piece piecetype White) = show piecetype
```

Explanations:

- `Piece` is a datatype with constructor `Piece` (both type name and constructor are same for your case) and  not a tuple. So you should pattern match on constructor and not on tuple.
- `toUpper` and `toLower` are present in `Data.Char` and work on `Char` while things like `"B"` are `String` ( `String` is type synonym for `[Char]`). So to make a `String` uppercase you can use `map toUpper`.
- Comparing string like `show color == "B"` is not very efficient instead you can use pattern matching on the constructor names.

Comment: I'd also recommend pattern matching on the color directly instead of doing `if show color == "B" ...`